# Capturing a shift+tab keypress in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to capture shift + tab in c# using the following cpp syntax:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000)
{
   // The key is currently down
}
```

Can anyone point me to the c# equivalent?

Thanks,
Drew

Comment: Check **[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo.key.aspx)** out from MSDN

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax is almost exactly the same.

You'll need to declare the `GetAsyncKeyState` method like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetAsyncKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys vKey);
```

Instead of `VK_SHIFT`, you can write `Keys.Shift`

Also, C# doesn't impicitly convert `int` to `bool`, so you'll need to compare that to `0`.

Therefore, you'll need to write

```
if ((GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.Shift) & 0x8000) != 0)
```

---

## However,

You can do this without P/Invoke by checking [`Control.ModifierKeys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.modifierkeys.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the syntax.  Unfortunately, this is a VSTO word add-in, so I have to use P/Invoke.

Comment: You can use Control.ModifierKeys even in VSTO. Simply add a reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll.